# flex, 3d object translation and rotation

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to move between (rotated) object in flex along x, y, or z as an independent observer.
The movement relative to x, y works ok, but when I go along the z axis, the observer behaves as it was apart of the xyz system of the objects and doesn't go straightforward to the object but in diagonal for example.
Here is some tryout code
thanks for the help

A screenshot can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyuhN.png

```
var dx1:Number=Math.cos(degToRad(currentZRotation))*xDiff;
        var dy1:Number=-Math.sin(degToRad(currentZRotation))*xDiff;
        var dy2:Number=Math.cos(degToRad(currentZRotation))*yDiff;
        var dx2:Number=Math.sin(degToRad(currentZRotation))*yDiff;
        xDiff=dx1+dx2;
        yDiff=dy1+dy2;
        var xyx:Number=Math.cos(degToRad(currentYRotation))*xDiff;
        var aux:Number=Math.sin(degToRad(currentYRotation))*xDiff;
        var xxy:Number=Math.sin(degToRad(currentXRotation))*aux;
        var xxz:Number=Math.cos(degToRad(currentXRotation))*aux;
        var yxz:Number=-Math.sin(degToRad(currentXRotation))*yDiff;
        var yxy:Number=Math.cos(degToRad(currentXRotation))*yDiff;
        var zyz:Number=0;
        var zxy:Number=0;
        var zyx:Number=0;
        zxy=sign(Math.cos(degToRad(currentYRotation)))*Math.sin(degToRad(currentXRotation))*zDiff;
        aux=Math.cos(degToRad(currentXRotation))*zDiff;
        zyx=-sign(Math.cos(degToRad(currentXRotation)))*Math.sin(degToRad(currentYRotation))*aux;
        zyz=Math.cos(degToRad(currentYRotation))*aux;   
        currentX += xyx+zyx;
        currentY += yxy+zxy+xxy;
        currentZ += zyz+xxz+yxz;
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would highly recommend getting hold of a good book on 3D graphics and reading up on transformation matrices.  It will save you a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: I'd recommend providing some screenshots of what you want it to be and what it actually is.  And possibly a runnable application so it is easy for us to test.  @Rob Agar do you have any book recommendations?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Alan Watt's 3D Computer Graphics was the pick of the bunch when I was getting my head round the concepts, but that was some time ago :\

Comment: thanks for the tips. I've also added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Wait, are you implementing your own rudimentary 3d engine? Why not use one of the MANY open source alternatives out there that already does all this stuff? Like [Yogurt](http://www.yogurt3d.com/), [Alternativa](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/)(my personal fav) or [Away3d](http://away3d.com/).

Also, just from looking at your code that I can say you're overcomplicating the problem by quite a bit. If I were you, I'll look into Vectors more than going with degree calculations (trust me on this) and look into Matrices like Rob mentioned. This might also all be over your head (Fisix is hard :P), so my recommendation is using the premade 3d engines.

Comment: Thanks :) For the learning sake I want to try implementing this without adding a 3d engine. So back to geometry.

Comment: Again, don't use geometry.  That is not how physics work.  They work with vectors.  You can try to learn this way, but you're already heading in the wrong way.  You should also try to learn how to enhance performance on your actionscript.  You might want to look at the other engines since they're open source and get an idea how to do the transform.